# clang 3.8 - How to stop clang from creating AST of system headers?

Tags: c++, clang, header-files, abstract-syntax-tree

I recently started using using Clang 3.8 on Fedora 22 machine to make a tool which parses the clang AST and extracts some information from AST nodes. The tool is expected to read in C,C++, and SystemC files.

When I read a file and dump the AST using my tool, it shows me the AST for the system headers as well.

Hence my question:
 How can I ask my tool not to display the AST of system headers? Because i will be modifying the files and I am afraid that system headers will create an overhead.

PS. I have already tried isInSystemHeader() function, but it is not helpful. Because the parser just keeps digging in the system headers and at some point generates the error. The error is

```
"/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Basic/SourceLocation.cpp:117: bool clang::FullSourceLoc::isInSystemHeader() const: Assertion `isValid()' failed.
```

Aborted (core dumped)"

Pointers to solution, or solutions will be highly appreciated :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
FullSourceLoc fullSourceLoc(decl->getLocation(), astContext.getSourceManager());
if (fullSourceLoc.isValid() && !fullSourceLoc.isInSystemHeader()) {
     // system header excluded here
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.